# implement your own plomb function in matlab

Tags: matlab, spectrum

i am trying to implement my own  code for plomb(because i dont have matlab 2014b),here is my code

```
function [PLS,f]=plomb(x,t);
diff=t(2)-t(1);
fs=1/diff;
x_mean=mean(x);
variance=var(x);
f=fs*(0:length(x)-1)/length(x);
part1=sum(((x-x_mean).*cos(2*pi*f*t)))^2/sum(cos(2*pi*f*t).^2);
part2=sum(((x-x_mean).*sin(2*pi*f*t)))^2/sum(sin(2*pi*f*t).^2);
PLS=(part1+part2)/(2*variance);
```

it is  done using help of following site

http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/plomb.html?refresh=true

i have tested this code on following simple sinusoidal signal

```
>> t=0:0.01:2.93;
>> x=sin(2*pi*10*t);
```

but i got error

```
[PLS,f]=plomb(x,t);
Error using  * 
Inner matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in plomb (line 7)
part1=sum(((x-x_mean).*cos(2*pi*f*t)))^2/sum(cos(2*pi*f*t).^2);
 i did not get point,what i am doing incorrectly?thanks in advance
```

EDITED :

i have change my code to  this

```
for k=1:length(x)
part1(k)=sum(((x-x_mean).*cos(2*pi*f(k)*t)))^2/sum(cos(2*pi*f(k)*t).^2);
part2(k)=sum(((x-x_mean).*sin(2*pi*f(k)*t)))^2/sum(sin(2*pi*f(k)*t).^2);
PLS=(part1+part2)/(2*variance);
end
```

is it ok?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need to perform elementwise operations there. So, do this -

```
part1=sum(((x-x_mean).*cos(2*pi.*f.*t))).^2/sum(cos(2*pi.*f.*t).^2);
part2=sum(((x-x_mean).*sin(2*pi.*f.*t))).^2/sum(sin(2*pi.*f.*t).^2);
```

Comment: @rayryeng Happens on crazy days! ;)

Comment: thanks my friend    and what about time offset ? what is that ?how can i calculate  ?

Comment: @datodatuashvili I don't think I can help you with the functionality of it, I only suggested you to get rid of the dimension error.

Comment: thanks very much guys,i think i solved offset problem,i will check it later again

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that statement is trying to compute element by element operations but only some of the expression is doing so.  In particular, `f` and `t` are both vectors yet you are trying to multiply them with `*` which is interpreted as matrix multiplication.  In addition, you're missing a `.` operator for the first power of 2 in the statement, but you seem to have done this for the second power of 2 statement.

As such, you need to modify the two statements to:

```
part1=sum(((x-x_mean).*cos(2*pi.*f.*t))).^2/sum(cos(2*pi.*f.*t).^2);
part2=sum(((x-x_mean).*sin(2*pi.*f.*t))).^2/sum(sin(2*pi.*f.*t).^2);
```

Comment: i also use  loop like this for k=1:length(x)
part1(k)=sum(((x-x_mean).*cos(2*pi*f(k)*t)))^2/sum(cos(2*pi*f(k)*t).^2);
part2(k)=sum(((x-x_mean).*sin(2*pi*f(k)*t)))^2/sum(sin(2*pi*f(k)*t).^2);
PLS=(part1+part2)/(2*variance);

Comment: point which i did not understand how to introduce  offset ?i meant The time offset

Comment: That loop doesn't make much sense.  The output of each expression would be a vector, yet you are trying to assign this output to a single element in `part1`.  Stick with vectorized operations.

Comment: @datodatuashvili Add that code to your question and show us the entire code?